# onkeyup event is not working in mobile phones

Tags: android, keyevent, mobile-browser

i m developing web app that must work in all smart phones
my code is like :

```
<input type='text' style='width:50px' onkeyup="abc()"/>
```

and js is like:

```
function abc(){
    alert("something");
}
```

its working in my computer's browser but its not working in my android phone's browser.
What to do..?

Comment: Have you disabled javascript?

Comment: Did you solve this? I am having a problem like this where my "keyup" event is being triggered repeatedly.

Comment: i did little mistake in my code.. give me your code so that i can suggest u something..

Answer (score 0):

You could try debugging your mobile browser with something like [WEINRE](http://muellerware.org/papers/weinre/manual.html) or install [Adobe Shadow](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/shadow/) (which uses WEINRE).

**WEINRE** is essentially a remote web inspector akin to Developer tools provided in Chrome or through Firefox Firebug.

That may help you see the errors and trace the problem.